# Pool de conexiones en java se

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de escritorio que se conecta a una base de datos mysql.Buscando en google encontre una nueva definicion para mi que es el pool de conexiones,pero vi que se usa con java EE .Se puede con Java SE tambien?

Comment: Aca hay un ejemplo de usar Hikari con java se. https://devs4j.com/2018/09/10/aprende-a-crear-un-connection-pool-utilizando-hikari-cp-en-espanol/

Comment: Gracias amigo,habia visto que se usaban las librerias de apache commons dbcp y commons pool.Estas son para java EE nada mas no?